# Get appId form Capacitor config file

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, quasar-framework, quasar

Is there a way to retrieve `appId` globally from `capacitor.config.json` file? In my Quasar app I use this for linking back to the app. So when I change it from 'dev' to 'prod' version of the app I need to change it in my Vue component file, `info.plist` for ios and `strings.xml` for android.

UPD:
From this thread I've known that [it's not possible](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2848) to handle just via `capacitor.config.json`. But what could be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since capacitor 3, the app info was moved from device plugin to app plugin.

First install the plugin

```
npm install @capacitor/app
npx cap sync
```

Now you can use it in your app

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

const info = await App.getInfo();
console.log(info);
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#appinfo

For Capacitor 2 and older you can use Device plugin, the getInfo function contains the appId

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Device } = Plugins;

const info = await Device.getInfo();
console.log(info);

// Example output:
{
  "diskFree": 12228108288,
  "appVersion": "1.0.2",
  "appBuild": "123",
  "appId": "com.capacitorjs.myapp",
  "appName": "MyApp",
  "operatingSystem": "ios",
  "osVersion": "11.2",
  "platform": "ios",
  "memUsed": 93851648,
  "diskTotal": 499054952448,
  "model": "iPhone",
  "manufacturer": "Apple",
  "uuid": "84AE7AA1-7000-4696-8A74-4FD588A4A5C7",
  "isVirtual":true
}
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device#getinfo

Comment: Cool! Thank you! And maybe you also have an idea how to pass to native platforms?

Comment: `appId` is no longer in this output - it's now on `App.getInfo()` on `@capacitor/app`